# openMP crushes without a good reason (?)

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I'm new to openMP and having some problems..
I tried to read the documentation but in vain.
Probably I'm missing something basic.
Any help will be appreciated.

Anyways, here's a skeleton of my program (complied with gcc -O3 -fopenmp.
I also tried without the -O3.) - apologies for any typos.
I tried to use openMP locks but it resulted in segmentation fault.
So instead I use my own locks.
Another issue is that I need an auxiliary (relatively large) buffer for each thread.
I tried allocating it as a local variable (on the stack?) but again the program crushes.
So instead I allocate it beforehand with malloc, one for each thread.
But however I try to do it, the program either crushes (stack overflow?) or it gets to an infinite loop (for reasons which I cannot understand).
The program runs without a problem without threading.

Are there any memory considerations (or otherwise) that I'm overlooking?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define MAXT 1000 /* maximal thread number */

#define LOCKNUM 1000


int *buffers[MAXT],*tab[LOCKNUM],num[LOCKNUM];

void mainloop();

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
  int maxt,t;
  double ticp,tocp;

  maxt=omp_get_max_threads();
  printf("maximal number of threads = %d\n",maxt);
  assert(maxt<=MAXT);

  for (t=0;t<maxt;t++) {
    buffers[t]=malloc(1<<20);
    assert(buffers[t]!=NULL);
  }
  for (t=0;t<LOCKNUM;t++) {
    tab[t]=malloc(1<<15);
    assert(tab[t]!=NULL);
  }


  ticp=omp_get_wtime();
  mainloop();
  tocp=omp_get_wtime();
  printf("Elapsed: %f seconds\n"tocp-ticp);
}


int dosth(int *);


void mainloop()
{

  int ht,mylock[LOCKNUM];

  for (ht=0; ht<LOCKNUM; ht++)
    mylock[ht]=0;

  int w;


#pragma omp parallel for
  for (w=0;w<1<<25;w++) {
    /* local variables */
    int i,j,a[10],b[20],tnum,h;
...
      /* local variables of total size < 1KB. My working hypothesis is that they are private by default. */

    if (!w) printf("%d threads currently working\n",omp_get_num_threads());

    tnum=omp_get_thread_num();

...
      /* do some work using array buffers[tnum] */


...

      /* calculate some integer h */

    assert(h<LOCKNUM);
    while (mylock[h]) dosth(mylock);
    mylock[h]=1;
...
    tab[h][num[h]++]= ....
...
    mylock[h]=0;


  ...

#pragma omp critical (update)
    {
...
    }

  }

}


/* do some pointless work to kill time */

int dosth(int *dummy)
{
  int i;
  int s=0;
  for (i=0;i<1000;i++)
    s+=i*(i-17);
  return(s);
}
```

Comment: For future reference, in English, when a program fails it does not "crush", it "crashes".

Comment: I'm going to guess that the reason for your crashes is not represented in the code you've presented here.  I can see ample reason for `while (mylock[h]) dosth(mylock);` to loop infinitely, but I'm not certain that's representative of your actual program.  It's unlikely that we can help you unless you present a *bona fide* [mcve].